# Sum of numbers from 0 to 10^18 with modulus 10^9+7

Tags: c++, algorithm, overflow, modular-arithmetic

How to find sum of numbers from 0 to n modulus 10<sup>9</sup> + 7, where n ≤ 10<sup>18</sup>?

I want to store the result in long long int only and not in array or string.
My code results in a run time error.

```
const unsigned int m = 1000000007;

long long int n;
cin >> n;
long long int s = 0;
for (long long int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    s = ((s % m) + (i % m)) % m;
}
cout << s << endl;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sum of *n* natural numbers is given by the formula, `n * (n + 1) / 2`. So, you don't need to iterate over *n* to calculate the sum.

As, *n* can be up-to 10<sup>18</sup>, computing the sum using, `(n * (n + 1) / 2) % MOD` would result in integer overflow. Instead, modular arithmetic property, `(a * b) % MOD` is congruent to `((a % MOD) * (b % MOD)) % MOD`, should be used to compute the sum. .

Thus, the sum can be computed using:
`((n % MOD * (n + 1) % MOD) % MOD) / 2`

The code would look something like this,

```
const long long int MOD = 1e9 + 7;
long long int n;

cin >> n;

long long s
s = ((n % MOD * (n + 1) % MOD) % MOD) / 2;

cout << s << '\n';
```